# TypeScript: pass the ReturnType of a nested function in an object that uses Interface

Tags: typescript, class, types, typescript-generics

I want to create a structure where I have an Interface like this:

```
interface PageData {
    data: (this: Page) => object;
    methods: (this: Page) => { [methodName: string]: () => any };
    main: (this: Page) => void;
}
```

and a class that uses this data to create a new instance:

```
class Page {
    name: string;
    data: object;
    methods: object;
    constructor(name: string, data: PageData) {
        this.name = name;
        this.data = data.data.call(this);
        this.methods = data.methods.call(this);
        data.main.call(this);
    }
}
```

Now how would I pass the ReturnType of the data and methods functions to Page.data and Page.methods? I searched for ReturnType, Generics and so on and at this point im just confused. Maybe its not even possible? I want to have this Interface so I can use it in many files. My folder structure would be something like:

`src/
src/main.ts
src/Page.ts
src/pages/demo.ts`

In demo.ts i want to export an object with the interface PageData:

```
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            customName: this.name + "demo"
        }
    },
    methods: function() {
        return {
            doSomething: () => this.data.customName.repeat(2)
        }
    },
    main: function() {
        console.log(this.data.customName);
        console.log(this.methods.doSomething());
    }
} as PageData
```

In main.ts I would get the data with require. Like `new Page("demo", require("src/pages/demo.ts"))`.

I tried to find any example that resembles that what I am trying to do but I could not find anything. The only things I found was how to get the ReturnType of a function, but not a function that is in an object that uses an Interface.

With this complete example there are three errors:
Line 27, 31: `Property 'customName' does not exist on type 'object'.`
Line 32: `Property 'doSomething' does not exist on type 'object'.`

```
interface PageData {
        data: (this: Page) => object;
        methods: (this: Page) => { [methodName: string]: () => any };
        main: (this: Page) => void;
}

class Page {
        name: string;
        data: object;
        methods: object;
        constructor(name: string, data: PageData) {
                this.name = name;
                this.data = data.data.call(this);
                this.methods = data.methods.call(this);
                data.main.call(this);
        }
}

export default {
        data: function() {
                return {
                        customName: this.name + "demo"
                }
        },
        methods: function() {
                return {
                        doSomething: () => this.data.customName.repeat(2)
                }
        },
        main: function() {
                console.log(this.data.customName);
                console.log(this.methods.doSomething());
        }
} as PageData
```

Comment: I don't *quite* understand what you mean by "pass the ReturnType of the data and methods functions to Page.data and Page.methods".  I'd recommend making your code into a [mcve] by showing exactly what isn't working as you expect (error messages when you try to access properties on the instance of `Page` created by `new Page()...`, for example?)  Good luck!

Comment: I added more information and fixed an error in default methods and main function.

Comment: If I fix those errors, what do you expect to be able to do with `const page = new Page("demo", require("src/pages/demo.ts"))`? Do you expect it to remember that `page.data.customName` exists?  Or are you fine with `page.data` being an `object` as in your definition of `Page`?

Comment: Your implementation will throw runtime errors as-is, because the `Page` constructor doesn't copy the actual `data` or `method` properties into `this`.  So when you run it, `this.customName` and `this.doSomething` will be undefined, causing an error inside the `main` call.  Can you fix this?

Comment: Yes i want that it remembers that `page.data.customName` exists. I already changed `this.customName` to `this.data.customName`, maybe you need to hard reload the browser?

Comment: I know, or i am pretty sure that the `object` in the definition of  `Page` is wrong, i just dont know what to put there. I suspect that `ReturnType` is the right thing but `ReturnType<typeof PageData.data>` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to make your `PageData` and `Page` types generic in the types of a `Page` object's `data` and `methods` properties, like this:

```
interface PageData<D extends object, M extends Record<keyof M, () => any>> {
  data: (this: Page<D, M>) => D;
  methods: (this: Page<D, M>) => M;
  main: (this: Page<D, M>) => void;
}

class Page<D extends object, M extends Record<keyof M, () => any>> {
  name: string;
  data: D;
  methods: M;
  constructor(name: string, data: PageData<D, M>) {
    this.name = name;
    this.data = data.data.call(this);
    this.methods = data.methods.call(this);
    data.main.call(this);
  }
}
```

(Note: given that your example `PageData` is explicitly using arrow function properties instead of methods inside its `methods` property, I'm not going to bother with the [`ThisType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypet), as they don't have their own `this` context to worry about.)

---

Then there's the issue with making a `PageData` object and resolving those errors.

I assume you don't want to hand-annotate the `this` parameter of all of its properties, and instead would like the compiler to infer the appropriate `this` type.  Unfortunately, that probably won't be possible all at once with a single object (see [relevant GitHub comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34865#issuecomment-548867473)); the compiler would need to both build and infer the type at the same time, which it's not great at.  It's better at being able to do things sequentially.  So, if, as in your example, the `data` property isn't really dependent on anything, the `methods` property is dependent on `data`, and the `main` property is dependent on both `data` and `methods`, then you could consider making a [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for `PageData` objects that creates them sequentially:

```
const pageDataBuilder = {
  data: <D extends object>(data: (this: Page<any, any>) => D) => ({
    methods: <M extends Record<keyof M, () => any>>(methods: (this: Page<D, any>) => M) => ({
      main: (main: (this: Page<D, M>) => void) => ({
        data, methods, main
      })
    })
  })
};
```

And here's how you could use it:

```
const data = pageDataBuilder.data(
  function () {
    return {
      customName: this.name + "demo"
    }
  }).methods(function () {
    return {
      doSomething: () => this.data.customName.repeat(2)
    }
  }).main(function () {
    console.log(this.data.customName);
    console.log(this.methods.doSomething());
  });
```

That compiles  with no errors, and then this works:

```
const page = new Page("demo", data);
page.data.customName; // string
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwOYQCJzHAHm2QgA9IQATAZ2QHsAjAKwgTABpkBZE8iK2gCVWdKJQIBrCAE86MbpwAUASmQBeAHzI4IaRq0BvALAAoZMkp44ALmSKwAC2DVb6LEU5cNqzcmwBuU3MAWwhHOhpbeycXNEwID25vdS0uQLNkYLhQKMdnV3jErx8tADc6YEp0gF9TUwQAGzhqWjcE4jIKGnpmVg5uXi6hETFJGTkFOxLtXX1kYwyQOFDbajAoUAx080t8WwCgzLCHCNi0w4Q6EDWoAFc2UUUlleQbzc5dmzisXHwi5IW5nMeWoADpnig1MgIdsgSDQZ91BYrAiUQg4A0GtFnMpYcCYqDQuFulDPoTjqdQejMdjqLjDjsUVlQFSMViQfSMrUTNzkPUrmtkAAHeK-OAAIVuwAalGgSMByL2yCIg343UYLDYGkUn1yMQK7h00k4RuSvmw00UCpCFMiyp4nTVw0uoyksnkXCU01N2qJJzttIN7RNs2mXEt1qBzJAUWjevy32DSWm5UqEYZQMZ+E4ftOOeyIAz5mqygzJcO5Z56X51zAirgSJFPyskulsqgqPwikOMFuIDYwCuU3mGagYVuUBAI4ymYQtzWdGCADllhBbPCIcgANTIABEsuCdF3ZYrynJxOoil7-bAg6nKmnmbHYAnU8jOzoAGVF8dNlFpvCZJzguy6rqCY5ChAeCKAATKWM7ILyiFntGV59gOQ4PpGlzXHQDQQKCDR0BgtKdnAVLzmAi4rqEnKzgKeEEURJHwrmNAIl+P55CAJHKHRyHViYOGCk2kLQhAADuiaKPuECHruHxWJyolkRRIE0RA-jIAA9NprzrJsQA)

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much, for the code and for the links! That helped me a lot to understand how it works and also what i am actually trying to do.